# Chrome not rendering Font without Solid Fill

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I am trying to use a font located at [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/helloetchasketch.font) called HelloEtchASketch.

I downloaded the font and placed it in my project folder. The font renders as expected in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome.

Safari:

[image: Test Image]

Chrome:

[image: Test Image]

The nice sketched effect in the character's body is seen in Safari, but not in Chrome. Chrome seems to fill the body of the character.

Could anyone please suggest a cause and possible solution for this? I have searched for hours for an answer but I have not been able to find anything useful.

Note: I am using Chrome on OS X.

I appreciate your time! Thanks.

Comment: antialiasing? they are different rendering engines these days.

Comment: @DanielA.White when I add:
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
to the css, the font on Safari has thinner lines, but on Chrome it remains with a solid fill.

Comment: which `font-weight` ? What's the element you use it in ? Works for me on chrome with `font-weight:normal`, or `@font-face`'s `font-weight : bold` in `<hX>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring with a friend, we found out that in Chrome, when you place text between header tags,  for example, the stroke of the font becomes very large.

Setting this property in the h1 element in css helped:

font-weight: 100;

It only happens in Chrome.

I hope this can help anyone else who may come across this in the future!

Comment: :-) this answers my comment. So a better fix, if you intend to use this font only in normally bold elements (it seems this font is made for it), is to tell the browser that this font is intended to be bold. `@font-face{ font-family: ... src: url(... font-weight: bold}` This way, the browser won't try to create boldness by itself.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that suggestion!